# Search array for specific value and find its position?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I want to search for a specific value (that I know is in the array).  I just need to return the position where this value is so later I can recall it with array[2] and that value will come up.

So if the array looks like:

```
11292929, 199309832092, 2198829922, 938430000113
```

If I search the array for `2198829922` I want to call the array later and use `array[2]` for `2198829922` to show up.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Have you tried it? What problems did you hit at implementing? Have you searched the web, or the docs?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: use indexOf function for this.

Comment: Thanks all, I honestly thought it would be way more complicated than just indexOf so didn't even give it a try first.  Live and learn another day on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `indexof()` method on the array.
So it would be
`var indexOfItem = arr.indexOf(2198829922);`

Comment: Thank,s I didn't think it'll be this simple so that's why I asked this (apparently stupid) question :/